# How to move a button near to cursor when cursor is coming and move a little more far when cursor is leaving

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mousemove

I am trying to create a little mouse moving animation. When cursor comes near to the button I call it  *borderline* - Certain distance from the button, the button moves to the cursor direction.

Here I have shown two steps dashed *borderline* with css just for clarity and understanding. 
I have created the nearest *borderline* from code by calculating the center point of button and decreasing and adding width and height of the button for both x and y axis.

And I want to solve this in the same process I'm working not by adding other `event-listener` tothe `parent-elements` of the button.

Here is what I have tried..

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
let { width, height, x: buttonX, y: buttonY } = button.getBoundingClientRect(); // gives you width, height, left-X,top-y of the button

buttonX = buttonX + width / 2; //  center point of button on x-axis
buttonY = buttonY + height / 2; //  center point of button on y-axis

/*************** Functions ***************/

let distance = width;
let mouseHasEntered = true;
let mouseIsInButtonTerritory;

function mouseMove(e) {
  const x = e.x; // current x of cursor
  const y = e.y; // current y of cursor

  const leftBorderLine = buttonX - distance;
  const rightBorderLine = buttonX + distance;
  const topBorderLine = buttonY - distance;
  const bottomBorderline = buttonY + distance;
  const xWalk = (x - buttonX) / 2; // the distance to move the button when mouse moves on X axis
  const yWalk = (y - buttonY) / 2; // the distance to move the button when mouse moves on Y axis

  mouseIsInButtonTerritory =
    x > leftBorderLine &&
    x < rightBorderLine &&
    y > topBorderLine &&
    y < bottomBorderline; // becomes true if  mouse is inside all of these border-line

  if (mouseIsInButtonTerritory) {
    if (mouseHasEntered) {
      // this must happen only once to create outside borderline
      //creating another level borderline by incresing distance;
      // while cursor is returing the button comes out of nearest border-line and return from this borderline
      distance = distance + distance;
      mouseHasEntered = false;
    }
    catchCursor(xWalk, yWalk); // call the function when mouse in in the button's territory
  } else {
    resetPositon();
  }
}

function catchCursor(xWalk, yWalk) {
  // translates the button in the direction where cursor is.
  button.style.transform = `translate(${xWalk}px, ${yWalk}px)`;
}

function resetPositon() {
  // resets the postion of the button as it was initial.
  button.style.transform = `translate(${0}px, ${0}px)`;
  mouseHasEntered = true;
  // when button is return to it's position (mouseHasEntered = true) lets to increase the initial borderline of button for the next time
}

/*************** Event-handler ***************/

window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
window.addEventListener("mouseout", resetPositon);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --gutter-lg: 4rem;
  --gutter-md: 3rem;
  --gutter-sm: 1rem;
  --gutter-xm: 1rem;
  --color-white: #fff;
  --color-black: #000;
}

body {
  background: var(--color-black);
  font: 16px verdana;
  color: var(--color-white);
}

.banner {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.button {
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.button-wrap-wrapper {
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.button-wrap {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  margin: auto;
  /* background: orange; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
}

.button__like-text {
  display: block;
  color: var(--color-black);
  background: var(--color-white);
  width: var(--gutter-lg);
  height: var(--gutter-lg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
      <div class="button-wrap-wrapper">
        <div class="button-wrap">
          <div class="button">
            <span class="button__like-text">
              Like
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

What is not working as expected is: `mouseIsInButtonTerritory` becomes true and I am trying to increase the `borderline` here

```
 if (mouseHasEntered) {
      // this must happen only once to create outside borderline
      //creating another level borderline by incresing distance;
      // while cursor is returing the button comes out of nearest border-line and return from this borderline
      distance = distance + distance;
    }
```

the button keep following the cursor all the time.

What I am trying to solve is if the cursor is coming out of the both *borderlines* the button must cross the first *borderline* and come near to the last *borderline* and go back where it was in initial phase.

I am not getting where I am doing wrong. is there a anything that is missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you should reset the distance when mouse leave. (I'm not sure, just guess this is what you want, since you write `mouseHasEntered = true` when reset)
- since you handle mouse leave yourself (the `else mouseIsInButtonTerritory` part) do not listen to window.

---

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
let { width, height, x: buttonX, y: buttonY } = button.getBoundingClientRect(); // gives you width, height, left-X,top-y of the button

buttonX = buttonX + width / 2; //  center point of button on x-axis
buttonY = buttonY + height / 2; //  center point of button on y-axis

/*************** Functions ***************/

let distance = width;
let mouseHasEntered = true;
let mouseIsInButtonTerritory;

function mouseMove(e) {
  const x = e.x; // current x of cursor
  const y = e.y; // current y of cursor

  const leftBorderLine = buttonX - distance;
  const rightBorderLine = buttonX + distance;
  const topBorderLine = buttonY - distance;
  const bottomBorderline = buttonY + distance;
  const xWalk = (x - buttonX) / 2; // the distance to move the button when mouse moves on X axis
  const yWalk = (y - buttonY) / 2; // the distance to move the button when mouse moves on Y axis

  mouseIsInButtonTerritory =
    x > leftBorderLine &&
    x < rightBorderLine &&
    y > topBorderLine &&
    y < bottomBorderline; // becomes true if  mouse is inside all of these border-line

  if (mouseIsInButtonTerritory) {
    if (mouseHasEntered) {
      // this must happen only once to create outside borderline
      //creating another level borderline by incresing distance;
      // while cursor is returing the button comes out of nearest border-line and return from this borderline
      distance = distance + distance;
      mouseHasEntered = false;
    }
    catchCursor(xWalk, yWalk); // call the function when mouse in in the button's territory
  } else {
    resetPositon();
  }
}

function catchCursor(xWalk, yWalk) {
  // translates the button in the direction where cursor is.
  button.style.transform = `translate(${xWalk}px, ${yWalk}px)`;
}

function resetPositon() {
  // resets the postion of the button as it was initial.
  button.style.transform = `translate(${0}px, ${0}px)`;
  if(!mouseHasEntered)distance/=2;
  mouseHasEntered = true;
  // when button is return to it's position (mouseHasEntered = true) lets to increase the initial borderline of button for the next time
}

/*************** Event-handler ***************/

window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
//window.addEventListener("mouseout", resetPositon);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --gutter-lg: 4rem;
  --gutter-md: 3rem;
  --gutter-sm: 1rem;
  --gutter-xm: 1rem;
  --color-white: #fff;
  --color-black: #000;
}

body {
  background: var(--color-black);
  font: 16px verdana;
  color: var(--color-white);
}

.banner {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.button {
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.button-wrap-wrapper {
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.button-wrap {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  margin: auto;
  /* background: orange; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
}

.button__like-text {
  display: block;
  color: var(--color-black);
  background: var(--color-white);
  width: var(--gutter-lg);
  height: var(--gutter-lg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
      <div class="button-wrap-wrapper">
        <div class="button-wrap">
          <div class="button">
            <span class="button__like-text">
              Like
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Yes !! this is what the result must be. But I could not get why : :else { resetPositon(); } do not listen do the window.

Comment: @SandeshSapkota well, I mean you should remove `window.addEventListener("mouseout", resetPositon);`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your intention correctly, I think you need to:

1. **add** `buttonWrapWrapper` selector

```
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
const buttonWrapWrapper = document.querySelector(".button-wrap-wrapper");
```

2. **attach** the event listeners to `buttonWrapWrapper` instead of `window`:

```
buttonWrapWrapper.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
buttonWrapWrapper.addEventListener("mouseout", resetPositon);
```

Comment: well, there is no `button.addEventListener` in OP's code.

Comment: @appleapple, sorry, instead of `window.addEventListener`. I've fixed it

Comment: @MuhammedIbrahim I don't want to solve it by adding other event handlers and working with other elements. I have created a  one step of borderline on code   through calulation. comment  `if (mouseHasEntered) {}` block and see you will understand more.